# fgets doesnt get the last character

Tags: c, string, file-io, char, fgets

for some reason, when I print phrase in the following code I discover that the fgets function doesn't get the last characater in the text file. I already checked mone1 and saw that its given enough space for the text in the file. Does someone have an explanation and a soloution to that occurrence?

Tnx, Dean.

p.s I'm pretty sure the length of the string is not a problem cause even when I'm changing it to 2 characters it's still prints only the first(doesn't print the last char), and it's all written in the same line.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    printf("ss");
    FILE * sent=NULL;
    FILE * voca=NULL;
    sent=fopen(argv[1],"r");
    voca=fopen(argv[2],"r");
        if(voca==NULL){
        printf("cannot open voca ");
        fclose(voca);
    }
    if(sent==NULL){
        printf("cannot open sent");
        fclose(sent);
    }
    int mone1=0;
    int mone2=0;
    while(EOF!=fgetc(sent))
        mone1++;    
    while(EOF!=fgetc(voca))
        mone2++;    
    fseek(sent,0L,SEEK_SET);
    fseek(voca,0L,SEEK_SET);
    char* phrase=(char*)(malloc(mone1*sizeof(char)));
    char* voc=(char*)(malloc(mone2*sizeof(char)));
    fgets(phrase,mone1,sent);
    fgets(voc,mone2,voca);
    printf("%s",phrase);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
char *fgets(char * restrict s, int n, FILE * restrict stream);
```

> The `fgets` function reads at most **one less than** the number of characters specified by `n` from the stream pointed to by stream into the array pointed to by `s`.

In another word, if you need to read `mone1` characters, pass in `n` as at least `mone1 + 1` and make sure the buffer is enough, too. The reason is `fgets` will add the trailing `\0` at the end.

Answer (score 1):

`fgets()` reads `size-1` characters from the `file stream` and adds Null character at the last.

For example

```
fgets(buf,2,file_stream);

buf[0]=some_character and buf[1]='\0';
```